# Tip: asdasdasdasdasdasd is abusive, and should be flagged as such, not as low-quality

Tags: discussion, flagging

Recent occurrence: [what changes the shape of an inlet](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/84827/14897)
Submitted review: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/55999

Use *rude or abusive* instead:

> [image]

---

Source: [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/392799)

> - *Abuse of the system or community* is everything that is created with the intention to harm them. [This includes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/262823) posts [by new users](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=26705146#26705146) that contain *no useful content at all* – i.e. gibberish posts along the lines of:
>
>   > asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd

Comment: also, don't use mod-attention flags, use r/a flags as said here and the post is handled faster

Comment: also, small side note: posts can go in the LQ review for system automatic flags, but this was not the case here

Comment: I hope this is not too offtopic, but; does anyone have a screenshot? I have been laughing after just reading this, But I couldn't see the post because it's deleted.

Comment: @Abdullah: here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFK6F.png

Answer (score 4):

This "question" (it's really a statement) is helpful and accurate.  Upvoted.

The bigger issue here is that the terminology that SE currently employs is confusing and ambiguous.  A reasonable person could easily conclude that
*"asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"* is very low quality and therefore select that option.

If you want to see change, the best option is likely for the moderators to ask SE to improve their UI to accommodate reasonable human behaviour instead of expecting people to change their behaviours based on a poorly designed UI.

This reminds me of a cockpit I redesigned.  The aircraft manufacturer initially asked me to include a note to pilots regarding how to use a particular control system.  After much effort, I was finally able to convince the manufacturer that it wasn't the pilots that needed to be retrained; it was the cockpit that needed be improved so it was obvious how to use all the controls.